# Inserting custom social media icons to nav.bar ( tb-megamenu )

Tags: 7, forms, routes, theming

I have been playing around all day and have been trying to get my social media in my navigation bar to the far right for people to click on and be directed to my social media account.

I am  using tb mega menu for my navigation bar and haven't had any luck getting them in there without messing with my site..

what i've done.

- created images put them in my images file on my theme im running
- went to style.css and tried to put the images in along with the path and href to my social media account exp. facebook, twitter

hasn't worked I would like to hear from you guys or if anyone has some code that I can slip in and where it would help out a lot, thanks.

MY CODE  in style.css

}

div=social media {

## facebook { background-image:url(/images/facebook.pn­g); width: 40px; height: 40px; position: relative; background-repeat: no-repeat; z-index: 10; margin-left: 880px; margin-top: -91px; padding-bottom: 115px;

}

## twitter { background-image:url(/images/twitter.png­); background-repeat: no-repeat; width: 40px; height: 40px; z-index: 10; margin-left: 30px;

}

## googleplus {background-image:url(/images/googleplus.pn­g); background-repeat: no-repeat; width: 40px; height: 40px; z-index: 10; margin-left: 30px;

}

## linkedin {background-image:url(/images/linkedin.png); background-repeat: no-repeat; width: 40px; height: 40px; z-index: 10; margin-left: 30px;

}

Comment: what do you mean by 'hasnt worked' - what hasn't worked? the images don't show? they're in the wrong position? they don't link? they're the wrong size? etc, etc... and how does it mess with you site?

Comment: sorry should have been more specific.I'm trying to do basically what this guy is doing  https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=erJ2GMCbMkc   when i try and put it in my style.file all it does is just disorganize my whole menu bar.... i was putting uploaded photos ( social media widgets ) into the images folder and creating a path in the code back to my images maybe im not 100% clear where to put the actual code ? but I have tried different variations with no success. They dont show up anywhere on my site, thank you.

Comment: Instated of writing comment it will easy to understand for everyone if you update your question with details.

Comment: add the html you're using to the question so we can see exactly how it is currently written

Comment: code added ^ there are no href's in the code right now as you may notice, just trying to set it up and get my icons visible